# Can JAXP be used to create HTML5 documents?

Tags: java, xml, html, jaxp

Are there elements in the HTML5 specification which can not be created with a XML library such as JAXP? One example are named HTML entities which are not defined in XML. Are there other areas which are incompatible?

Answer (score 0):

JAXP apparently only works on well formed XML. You'd need to convert the HTML to XHTML before subjecting it to the JAXP's standard parser.

```
    // Create Transformer
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    StreamSource xslt = new StreamSource(
            "src/blog/jaxbsource/xslt/stylesheet.xsl");
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer(xslt);

    // Source
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Library.class);
    JAXBSource source = new JAXBSource(jc, catalog);

    // Result
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

    // Transform
    transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Url:[https://dzone.com/articles/using-jaxb-xslt-produce-html][1]

Comment: This is not correct: with JAXP I am able to generate non well-formed output like `<html><br></html>` (note I am interested in writing, not reading, HTML documents)